# Change ASP.NET MVC controller variable on button press

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Very much new to ASP.NET MVC and C# for that matter. I'm building a simple booking overview.

My controller cabins return three different view data to the view.

- StartDate (which is the date to display from)
- EndDate (the last date which should be displayed too)
- Cabins (all booking information)

This works great and the default controller sets `StartDate` to `DateTime.Now`, and `EndDate` to `DateTime.Now.AddDays(20.0)`, which displays the upcoming 20 days in `Cabins/Index.cshtml`.

I now want to add a button on the view page which should change the `StartDate` and `EndDate` and thus display information for other dates. But I'm uncertain how to do that. I've tried various forms of methods through Google, but been unable to sort it out. Having a button press call the controller with a parameter `startDate` was one thing I tried. But it ended up doing nothing.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it after all.

Made sure my Index had an input parameter `public IActionResult Index(DateTime startDate)`

Then added a button to my view returning a parameter.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default active" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Cabins", new { startDate = startDate.AddDays(20.0)})'">Press Me</button>
```

Must've gotten something wrong the first times I tried it.